# Tags in DNG format file

Tags: python, computer-vision, dng

I am currently trying to understand DNG format and convert it to the simple RAW format file. And I have 2 questions: 
- is it possible that the same tag can appear several times in one DNG file which contains only one image?
- is it possible that the tag 273 does not give the offset to the image data?

You can find tags here : https://www.exiv2.org/tags.html

Thank you in advance for your help.